# wpf c# progress bar wont update untill after work is done when in background worker

Tags: c#, wpf

below is some code i am using to show a progress bar on window1. However when work is done on my main window the progress bar freezes then jumps to what ever stage the background worker is in. Is there anyway to have the progress bar constantly update. Even if work is being done in other windows

```
public SplashScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Timer();


            CreateBackGroundWorker();
           // int shareProgressBarValue = MainSharePage.shareProgressBarValue;

            LoginPage LoginPage = new LoginPage();
            LoginPage.Show();


        }

        private void CreateBackGroundWorker()
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           this.ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            //ShareProgressBarText.Text = (string)e.UserState;
        }

        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            worker.ReportProgress(0, String.Format("Processing Iteration 1."));
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                worker.ReportProgress((i + 1), String.Format("Processing Iteration {0}.", i + 2));
            }

            worker.ReportProgress(100, "Done Processing.");
        }
```

Comment: try this 
if (i %5 ==0)
 worker.ReportProgress((i + 1), String.Format("Processing Iteration {0}.", i + 2));

Comment: The above by itself should works properly... If it does not works, then you are probably doing something wrong elsewhere... Do you have a single UI thread and display your splash from it. Also, usually if you connect event handler manually, you should also remove them manually.

Answer (score 2):

I copy-pasted your code and removed the two lines dealing with your `LoginPage`, and it works flawlessly for me.

I then created and empty window as a replacement for `LoginPage`, added the same two lines to show it, and it still works.

I'd guess the problem is in your LoginPage, which must be blocking the UI thread one way or another.

Comment: Firstly Thank you for all your help so far :). and The login page essentially web scraps (grabs source code from website) then searches it for specific data. it does this 10 times. Which takes around 1 and a half minutes. During this time the progress bar wont update but once its finished it will jump to the end.    Thank you for all your help so far :)

Comment: Does it do it in a background worker as well? If not, I think you have your issue